# JMeter, Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am having a hard time get the "Regex Expression Extractor" working in Jmeter for the following:

Response Header is something like:

```
Set-Cookie: Token=dfrtydgsdttetert; Domain=.domain.ca; Path=/; 
Expires=Fri, 19 Oct 2018 18:54:18 GMT; Secure
ETag: W/"41c-gdf+/mzdw"
```

In JMeter Regular Expression Extractor:

```
Apply to: main sample and sub-samples
Field to check "Response Header"
Name of create Variable: extracted_token
Regular Expression: (?<=Token=)(.*)(?=; Domain)    <- the goal is 
the get the string "dfrtydgsdttetert"
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
Default Value: ERROR
```

I tried the above configuration and the extracted_token variable is always "ERROR"

if I change the regex to Token=
then I get:

```
extracted_id_token=null
extracted_id_token_g=0
extracted_id_token_g0=Token=
```

Please guide me how to fix my configuration so I can retrieve "dfrtydgsdttetert" in the response header.

Comment: Try `Token=(.*?); Domain`, or `Token=([^;]+);\s*Domain`

Comment: thank you! I tried your regex and it works as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this extraction the most performing way is to use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor):

[image: Boundary Extractor configuration]

If you still want [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

[image: Regular Expression Extractor configuration]

Comment: thank you for guide to me use the "Boundary Extractor". It works like a charm. Also thank you for the screenshots for both solutions!

Comment: happy I helped :-) you're welcome , and thanks for accepting and upvoting

Answer (score 0):

The "response header" you're trying to extract is basically a [HTTP Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), JMeter automatically handles cookies via [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) so you can just add it to your Test Plan and it will be way more convenient than manually extracting the values from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header and adding them to [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header.

If you need the cookie value for other reason you can get it from the HTTP Cookie Manager itself

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up (the change will be permanent)
3. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
4. That's it, now you will be able to refer your `Token` cookie value as `${COOKIE_Token}` where required, no need to extract it from the header.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)